# setting Column width of XamDataGrid in XAML

Tags: wpf, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I want to set the Column width of XamDataGrid in XAML. There is no Width Property available like

```
<ip:Field Label="Name" ........... Width="60"/>
```

Here is my sample code.

```
    <ip:XamDataGrid Name="PatientsList" DataSource="{Binding PatientsList}" SelectedItemsChanged="PatientsListSelectedItemsChanged"
                    XamDataGridBehaviours:XamDataGridBehavior.IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" GroupByAreaLocation="None">
        <ip:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
            <ip:FieldLayoutSettings AutoGenerateFields="False" SelectionTypeRecord="Extended" MaxSelectedRecords="1"/>
        </ip:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
        <ip:XamDataGrid.FieldSettings>
            <ip:FieldSettings AllowEdit="False" CellClickAction="SelectRecord"/>
        </ip:XamDataGrid.FieldSettings>
        <ip:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
            <ip:FieldLayout>
                <ip:FieldLayout.Fields>
                    <ip:Field Label="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Resources.StudyManager_colSex}}" Name="Sex"/>
                    <ip:Field Label="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Resources.StudyManager_colPatientId}}" Name="PatientId"/>
                    <ip:Field Label="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Resources.StudyManager_colLastName}}" Name="LastName" />
                    <ip:Field Label="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Resources.StudyManager_colFirstName}}" Name="FirstName" />
                    <ip:Field Label="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Resources.StudyManager_colPatientId}}" Name="FullName" />
                    <ip:Field Label="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Resources.StudyManager_colDOB}}" Name="DateOfBirth" />
                </ip:FieldLayout.Fields>
            </ip:FieldLayout>
        </ip:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
    </ip:XamDataGrid>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `Width` property was added to Fields in version 9.2. But there have always been `CellWidth`, `CellMinWidth`, and `CellMaxWidth` properties on the `FieldSettings` and each field has its own `FieldSettings`.

Comment: @Mike: Have u tried them in XAML? Atleast I ca't access them in v7.2.

Comment: You can define a field like this:
`<ip:Field Label="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Resources.StudyManager_colSex}}" Name="Sex">
  <ip:Field.Settings>
    <ip:FieldSettings CellMaxWidth="50" />
  </ip:Field.Settings>
</ip:Field>`

Comment: It just changes the width of the cell but not the complete column. Have u got what I mean? It looks very ugly.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Only one cell's width changes or all cells have their width changed but the field header doesn't change?

Comment: Yes the field header doesn't change.

Comment: I don't see that with version 9.2. It sounds like it is a bug that was fixed. Did you try installing the latest SR for 7.2?